# Help with $\int \frac{e^x}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Basically I was creating some integrals to practice with and I came across this one: 
$$\int \frac{e^x}{1+x^2}dx$$
So I first attempted doing the integral 'normally' and reached an answer where the integral was in its own answer:
$$e^{x}(\arctan x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^{2})-(xe^{x}\arctan x-\int \frac{e^{x}}{1+x^{2}}dx-\frac{1}{2}(x\ln(1+x^2-\frac{2x^{3}}{3})+C$$ Which I would assume not get me anywhere. 
So I decided to take a different approach and used Euler's formula to try to get somewhere. (Which I am not all that familair with so I may have made mistakes with this) I got the following:
 
$$\int \frac{e^x}{1+x^2}dx =i\int(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)/(1-\theta^{2})d\theta$$ where $x=i\theta$ and $dx=id\theta$
 
I didn't end up getting to an answer and ran in to a similar problem. Using wolframalpha to evaluate the integral it gives you 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29 
 which I do not understand how that answer is derived. 
 
So now I'm here, could anyone go through this in detail?

Comment: this integral doesen't have closed form expression in terms of elementary functions. You need the so called "Exponential integrals"

Comment: Basically, there are special functions for integrating $\int \frac{e^x}{x}$; with a little bit of shifting and playing with complex numbers you can recast your problem into two of those. This is what WA did.

Comment: The link won't paste correctly but copy and paste the following into your browser: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e^x%2F%281%2Bx^2%29dx

Comment: How would you go about doing this? I've attempted using the Exponential integral (as well as the Sine integral and Cosine integral) while doing this but I'm pretty sure I'm manipulating it wrong.

Comment: Do the partial fractions and then make the substitutions $u=x-i,u=x+i$ for the two integrals. Then factor out constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, this integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Concerning the result given by Wolfram Alpha, start considering that $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$ and perform partial fraction decomposition $$\frac 1{1+x^2}=\frac{i}{2 (x+i)}-\frac{i}{2 (x-i)}=\frac i 2\Big(\frac{1}{ x+i}-\frac{1}{x-i} \Big)$$ So $$I=\int \frac{e^x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac i 2\Big(\int \frac{e^x}{x+i}dx- \int \frac{e^x}{x-i}dx \Big)$$ $$I=\frac i 2\Big(e^{-i}\int \frac{e^{x+i}}{x+i}dx- e^i\int \frac{e^{x-i}}{x-i}dx \Big)$$

Now, you must remember that $$\int\frac {e^y}y dy=\text{Ei}(y)$$ which is the definition of the exponential integral. So $$I=\frac i 2\Big(e^{-i} \,\text{Ei}(x+i)-e^i\, \text{Ei}(x-i)\Big)$$